# Get Distinct Values from Two columns from outer sql query and List into one column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, query-optimization

I am trying to combine two column values into one column which will have distinct values.

I know we can do it using UNION if the query is formed directly on table, but If the data is formed on the go in SQL QUERY as given in example, which has more than 100 columns, how could i get the same output like explained with my data.

If i use same solution, i have to repeat the outer query twice to use union and then filter the unique data.

for eg:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, key_code, LOC_ID FROM
(
SELECT /*SOME 100 COLUMN*/, LOC_ID_1, LOC_ID_2 FROM TABLE 1
UNION ALL
SELECT /*SOME 100 COLUMN*/, LOC_ID_1, LOC_ID_2 FROM TABLE 2
UNION ALL
SELECT /*SOME 100 COLUMN*/, LOC_ID_1, LOC_ID_2 FROM TABLE 3
)
```

Is it a good solution to do similar to /*GETTING UNIQUE DATA WITH DELIMITER*/ union combination in given example.

--please guide if you need more information

```
/*CREATE TABLE*//
CREATE TABLE get_data (
id       NUMBER,
key_code NUMBER,
loc_id_1   VARCHAR2(20),
loc_id_2   VARCHAR2(20)
);

/*INSERT DATA*/
INSERT INTO get_data (id,key_code,loc_id_1,loc_id_2) values (1,101,'522','545');
INSERT INTO get_data (id,key_code,loc_id_1,loc_id_2) values (1,101,'522','546');
INSERT INTO get_data (id,key_code,loc_id_1,loc_id_2) values (1,101,'523','547');
INSERT INTO get_data (id,key_code,loc_id_1,loc_id_2) values (1,101,'550','545');
INSERT INTO get_data (id,key_code,loc_id_1,loc_id_2) values (2,201,'721','344');
INSERT INTO get_data (id,key_code,loc_id_1,loc_id_2) values (2,201,'821','451');
INSERT INTO get_data (id,key_code,loc_id_1,loc_id_2) values (2,201,'821','653');

/*QUERY DATA*/
SELECT * FROM get_data ORDER BY 1;

/*QUERY OUTPUT*/
ID  KEY_CODE    LOC_ID_1    LOC_ID_2
1   101     522     545
1   101     522     546
1   101     523     547
1   101     550     545
2   201     721     344
2   201     821     451
2   201     821     653

/*GETTING UNIQUE DATA WITH DELIMITER from both LOC_ID_1 AND LOC_ID_2*/
SELECT DISTINCT ID,key_code,
LISTAGG(loc_id,'||') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY loc_id) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS loc_id FROM (
SELECT ID,key_code,loc_id_1 AS loc_id FROM get_data
UNION
SELECT ID,key_code,loc_id_2 AS loc_id  FROM get_data
);

/*OUTPUT FROM ABOVE QUERY*/
ID KEY_CODE LOC_ID
1  101      522||523||545||546||547||550
2  201      344||451||653||721||821
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 19, `UNPIVOT` and then use `LISTAGG(DISTINCT ...) ...`:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       key_code,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT loc_id,'||') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY loc_id) AS loc_id
FROM   get_data
UNPIVOT (
  loc_id FOR key IN (loc_id_1 AS 1, loc_id_2 AS 2)
)
GROUP BY id, key_code;
```

Before Oracle 19, `UNPIVOT` then use `DISTINCT` and then `LISTAGG` in an outer query:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       key_code,
       LISTAGG(loc_id,'||') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY loc_id) AS loc_id
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         ID,
         key_code,
         loc_id
  FROM   get_data
  UNPIVOT (
    loc_id FOR key IN (loc_id_1 AS 1, loc_id_2 AS 2)
  )
)
GROUP BY id, key_code;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kmLezQhK)

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm and i need to upgrade my skills with few more analytical function though :)

Comment: @Anmol This does not use analytic functions; it uses aggregation as you only want a single row per group.